# Problem with passing ESCAPE key into stdin buffer in C Windows console

Tags: c

I want to put the text into my string and process it in an infinite loop, but I want to break the loop if the first character of the input is an ESCAPE key, but getchar returns 10 when I press ESCAPE followed by ENTER.
`printf` correctly prints the inputted character, but if I press ESCAPE nothing happens. I also don't want to use `_getch()` nor `getche()` which actually would solve my problem, but they also remove `c` from the buffer and doesn't display it properly.
What can I do?

```
int c;
while( 1 )
{
    c = getchar();
    printf( "c = %d\n", c );   // just for debug
    if( c == 27 ) break;
    else ungetc( c, stdin );
    fgets( StrIn, BUF_SIZE - 1, stdin );
    // REST OF CODE ********
}
```

EDIT I've just found Microsoft function

```
if( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_ESCAPE ) )
        break;
```

that works fine for me. Thanks for reading and for your time, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing the ESCAPE key on a keyboard does not usually send an ESCAPE character to a console, the application or OS will often process the character and not pass it on. I'd use a different character to represent the fact that you want to break, for example a '~'.

When you say it doesn't display right if you remove c from the buffer, perhaps you can just add the first character the buffer manually.

Add a macro for the break character

```
#define BREAK_CHAR '~'
```

The code spinet could then look like this:

```
int c;
while(1)
{
    c = getchar();

    /* check if we should break */
    if(c == BREAK_CHAR)
        break;

    /* assign the first character that was already read in */
    StrIn[0] = c;

    /* get the rest of the string */
    fgets( StrIn + 1, BUF_SIZE - 2, stdin );

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation in first paragraph. That had led me to the right conclusions. I've just found Microsoft function `GetAnyncKeyState` which works perfect for me and I'll stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

if you use windows - use windows specific functions as well. In my function ESC cancels the input.

```
char *wingetsn(char *str, size_t maxlen)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    int ch;
    int exit = 0;

    while (len < maxlen - 1 && !exit)
    {
        while(!_kbhit());
        switch((ch = _getch()))
        {
            case 27:
                str[0] = 0;
                exit = 1;
                break;
            case '\r':
                exit = 1;
                break;
            case '\n':
                break;
            default:
                printf("%c", ch);
                str[len++] = ch;
                break;
        }
    }
    str[len++] = 0;
    return str;
}
```